# Set.contains() in jvm doesn't work with Character class

Tags: collections, groovy

```
HashMap<Character, Character> charMap = new HashMap<Character ,Character>();
charMap['{'] = '}';
charMap['['] = ']';
charMap['('] = ')';

//println charMap.keySet()
Character ch = '{'
println charMap.keySet().contains(ch)
```

It simply prints false while it is obvious that my set contains '{", any idea why would this happen? (I am using groovy for testing...)

Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I am using groovy

Comment: I tried a straight Java version, using `charMap.put('{', '}')` instead of the array-like syntax. It printed "true". What did you see when you did the keySet printout?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Thanks for trying - this turns out to be a groovy string/char issues as explained below by dmahapatro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'{'` is a String and not a Character in groovy. To prove that, just print this in last line:

```
println charMap.keySet()*.class
```

It has to be explicitly type-casted to character:

```
HashMap<Character, Character> charMap = new HashMap<Character ,Character>();
charMap['{' as char] = '}';
charMap['['] = ']';
charMap['('] = ')';

//println charMap.keySet()
Character ch = '{'
println charMap.keySet().contains(ch)
```

This is how it works:

```
//String
assert 'a'.class == String

//Character
def c1= 'a' as char, c2= (char)'b' 
def c3= new Character(c2), c4= c2.charValue()
[c1, c2, c3, c4].each { assert it.class == Character }
assert c2 == c3 && c1 != c2
assert c1 < c2 && c1.compareTo(c2) == -1
assert c2.toString().class == String
```

Comment: @JeffWard Your script worked because you were asserting String to a String but a Character. :)

Comment: Makes sense. I'm somewhat of a groovy newb. I assumed it was related to the autoboxing differences from java.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this dmahapatro - groovy treats single quote as string rather than character, which used to be a convenience to me:)